# Simplify the code by using cycle function

Tags: javascript, cycle, simplify

I have multiply functions which are using the same cycle code and i'm wondering is it possible to simplify the code by having one cycle function so i could execute the code just by calling wanted function names.

Now:

```
for(var i=0;i<all;i++){ someFunction(i) }
```

Need:

```
cycle(someFunction);
function cycle(name){
    for(var i=0;i<all;i++){
       name(i);
    }
}
```

I tried to do this by using "window" and i get no error but the function is not executed.

```
var MyLines = new lineGroup();
MyLines.createLines(); // works
MyLines.addSpeed();    // doesn't work


var lineGroup = function(){
    this.lAmount = 5,
    this.lines = [],

    this.createLines = function (){
        for(var i=0,all=this.lAmount;i<all;i++){
            this.lines[i] = new line();
        }
    },

    this.addSpeed = function (){
        // no error, but it's not executing addSpeed function
        // if i write here a normal cycle like in createLines function
        // it's working ok
        this.linesCycle("addSpeed");
    },
    this.linesCycle = function(callFunction){
        for(var i=0,all=this.lAmount;i<all;i++){
            window['lineGroup.lines['+i+'].'+callFunction+'()'];
        }
    }
}

var line = function (){
    this.addSpeed = function (){
        console.log("works");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window['lineGroup.lines['+i+'].'+callFunction+'()'];
```

**literally** tries to access a property that starts with `lineGroups.lines[0]`. Such a property would only exist if you explicitly did `window['lineGroups.lines[0]'] = ...` which I'm sure you didn't.

There is no need to involve `window` at all. Just access the object's `line` property:

```
this.lines[i][callFunction]();
```

> i get no error but the function is not executed.

Accessing a non-existing property doesn't generate errors. Example:

```js
window[';dghfodstf0ap9sdufgpas9df']
```

This tries to access the property `;dghfodstf0ap9sdufgpas9df`, but since it doesn't exist, this will result in `undefined`. Since nothing is done with the return value, no change can be observed.

Answer (score 1):

Without a name space use:

```
window["functionName"](arguments);
```

SO wrap it up and use it thus:

```
cycle(someFunction);
function cycle(name){
    for(var i=0;i<all;i++){
       window[name](i);;
    }
}
```

With a namespace, include that:

```
window["Namespace"]["myfunction"](i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is likely a bit of overkill but using a function to make a class object (you can google the makeClass and why it is/could be useful) you can create instances of the object.

```
// makeClass - By Hubert Kauker (MIT Licensed)
// original by John Resig (MIT Licensed).
function makeClass() {
    var isInternal;
    return function (args) {
        if (this instanceof arguments.callee) {
            if (typeof this.init == "function") {
                this.init.apply(this, isInternal ? args : arguments);
            }
        } else {
            isInternal = true;
            var instance = new arguments.callee(arguments);
            isInternal = false;
            return instance;
        }
    };
}
var line = function () {
    this.addSpeed = function () {
        console.log("works");
    };
};
var LineGroup = makeClass();

LineGroup.prototype.init = function (lineNumber) {
    this.lAmount = lineNumber?lineNumber:5,
    this.lines = [],

    this.createLines = function (mything) {
        console.log(mything);
        var i = 0;
        for (; i < this.lAmount; i++) {
            this.lines[i] = new line();
        }
    },

    this.addSpeed = function () {
        console.log("here");
        this.linesCycle("addSpeed");
    },
    this.linesCycle = function (callFunction) {
        console.log("called:" + callFunction);
        var i = 0;
        for (; i < this.lAmount; i++) {
            this.lines[i][callFunction]();
        }
    };
};
var myLines = LineGroup();
myLines.createLines("createlines"); 
myLines.addSpeed();
//now add a new instance with 3 "lines"
var newLines = LineGroup(3);
newLines.createLines("createlines2")
console.log("addspeed is a:" + typeof newLines.addSpeed);
console.log("line count"+newLines.lAmount );
newLines.addSpeed();
```